# How to use column derived from SELECT subquery elsewhere in SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I have two database tables that look something like this:

```
+----------+      +------------------+
| Bookings |----->| Booking_Statuses |
+----------+      +------------------+
```

Context:

- `Booking_Statuses` is used to retain a history of the various stages that a booking can go through, such as `PENDING` or `ACCEPTED`, so I can construct a timeline of events for the booking. One `Booking` has many `Booking_Statuses`.
- I'm using PostgreSQL.

I am trying to query the bookings for a particular user, along with its latest status:

```
SELECT "bookings".*,
       (
            SELECT "status"
            FROM "booking_statuses"
            WHERE "bookings"."id" = "booking_statuses"."booking_id"
            ORDER BY "created_at" DESC
            LIMIT 1
       ) AS "last_status"
FROM "bookings"
WHERE "user_id" = $1
AND "last_status" IN ('PENDING', 'APPROVED')
```

It all works great, until I add the last line - `AND "last_status" IN ('PENDING', 'APPROVED')`, at which point I get the error: `column "last_status" does not exist`.

How can I use `last_status` outside of the SELECT subquery?

Comment: The error tells you the problem: `"last_status"` is the name of your subquery, not the name of a field. If you want to get your last status, you should look for `"last_status"."status"`.

Comment: Thanks, I learned something new today. I thought `last_status` was the name for the field. I'm one step closer, however the error is now `missing FROM-clause entry for table "last_status"`

Comment: Sounds like a job for a [lateral join](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html) (scroll down to section 7.2.1.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use something like this? You find your latest status id and then join it to bookings and then you can get the fields you need.

```
SELECT B.*, BB."status"
FROM "bookings" B
JOIN "booking_statuses" BB ON BB.id = (SELECT id
            FROM "booking_statuses"
            WHERE B."id" = "booking_statuses"."booking_id"
            ORDER BY "created_at" DESC
            LIMIT 1)
WHERE "user_id" = $1
AND BB."status" IN ('PENDING', 'APPROVED')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this suggestion. I tried it but I get a similar error (`missing FROM-clause entry for table "bookings"`).

Comment: @Obvious_Grapefruit Sorry about that looks like a I made mistake in the SELECT part,
I SELECTED B.Bookings.* , B is already Bookings so B.* is correct. 
If you still have an error please post what line is it on. 
Thanks

Comment: Thanks so much! If I remove the alias (`AS "last_status"` from the first line) and change the last line to use `BB.status` instead of the alias, it works perfectly!

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice I was using BB.Last_status. :D

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
SELECT bookings.*,
       status as last_status
FROM   bookings
       INNER JOIN booking_statuses
               ON id = booking_id
WHERE  user_id = $1
       AND last_status IN ( 'PENDING', 'APPROVED' )
ORDER  BY created_at DESC
LIMIT  1
```

Comment: This query will not work and is written in very bad style. Please read the OP's question more carefully and fix this.

Comment: @JonasMetzler I updated the syntax to be inline with the OP/more clean. Apart from that, what are you seeing about the query that won't satisfy the OP's data pull request? From my view, it provides the information.

Comment: I didn't save your previous query before your changes, so I can't tell you exactly what was incorrect there. But this query is still critical. Using * should be avoided, furthermore you don't use table aliases and don't tell from which table the columns should be used. It's very risky to assume as example the id column doesn't exist in both tables. You should also notice that it's bad style to put aliases in a where clause instead the real column name, meaning the column in the where clause should be status and not last_status.

Comment: @WriterState Hi there, thanks for your suggestion. I get an error with this query (`column reference \"id\" is ambiguous`) but explicitly stating the table names gets us one step further (`ON bookings.id = booking_statuses.booking_id`). However, now I get `column "last_status" does not exist`.

Comment: @Obvious_Grapefruit thanks for the reply, if you swap the last_status to the booking_statuses.status, you should get the result you are looking for. 

The answer to your original question, though, I think, is that you simply can't do what you were looking to do! The SQL engine gets mad.